# Keras Memory Leak

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory-leaks, keras, gpu

I am using Keras TensorFlow 1.8 and having a memory leak in my gpu (1080 ti). After training the network, my memory is  used even after closing python completely. In nvidia-smi it no longer shows the python but the memory usage is still there.

I cannot restart the computer because other users are running processes (I am sure they are not using the gpu).

[edit: I uploaded the wrong screenshot]

[image]

Comment: How did you close python? Killing it's process usually relieves itself of memory. What does sudo fuser -v /dev/nvidia* return

Comment: I closed PyCharm. The command shows a python instance, which is strange considering I have no applications running python

Comment: Well then close it!

Comment: I have closed it, i don't know why it shows a python running

Comment: As in you've killed the process with kill -9 <process number>

Comment: That fixed the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Always

```
K.clear_session()
```

where K is defined as

```
from keras import backend as K
```

at the end of your processing.

It prevents Tensorflow memory leakage.

You could also try

```
import gc
gc.collect()
```

or ,

from the beginning of your tf session, prevent tensorflow using the whole gpu power:

```
import tensorflow as tf
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```

Comment: I tried all these. They slow the memory leak but don't stop it completely.

Answer (score 0):

After speding way too much trying to `keras.clear_session()` and `gc.collect()` my way through this, I gave up and created a reliable workaround. It's a decorator that allows to run a function in a separate script.

It's called `scriptifier`, it installs via `pip install scriptifier`

It automatically generates the script and takes care of passing the arguments and returns as long as they are pickleable or keras models or lists of keras models... (for documentation see: [github](https://github.com/ben981/scriptifier))

It should look like this:

```
from scriptifier import scriptifier

def func_1(in):
    ...
    model.fit()
    ...
    return out

scriptified_func_1 = scriptifier.run_as_script(func_1)
out = scriptified_func_1(in)
```